Two definitions on being ramified
$\newcommand{\prime}{\mathfrak{p}}$$\newcommand{\OO}{\mathcal{O}}$There are two concepts of being ramified in algebraic number theory and quaternion algebra.

Definition A. Let $k/\Bbb Q$ be a number field and $\prime$ be a prime ideal of the ring of integers $\OO_k$, $\OO_k/\prime$ is a finite field and so had order of the form $p^f$ for some prime number $p$. Note that $\prime\cap\Bbb Z$ is a prime ideal $p'\Bbb Z$ of $\Bbb Z$ so that $\Bbb Z/p'\hookrightarrow\OO_k/\prime$. Thus $p' = p$ and we get a factorization
$$(p) = p\OO_k = \prime_1^{e_1}\cdots p_g^{e_g}\quad(\dagger)$$
where, for each $i$, $\OO_k/\prime_i$ is a field of order $p^{f_i}$ for some $f_i\geq 1$.
The prime number $p$ is said to be ramified in $k/\Bbb Q$ if some $e_i>1$ in $(\dagger)$.


Definition B. Let $B$ be a quaternion algebra over $\Bbb Q$. Let $B_p = B\otimes_{\Bbb Q}\Bbb Q_p$ where $\Bbb Q_p$ is a $p$-adic completion of $\Bbb Q$. If $B_p$ is a division algebra, we say $B$ is ramified at $p$.

I wonder if these two concepts are related or not.

See the related MO question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125043/ramified-quaternion-algebras#125068 .
